# Uploading CSV files to Google Cloud Storage Using .Net Libraries

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I need help on writing a code for uploading locally stored CSV files to Google cloud storage and then storing data from storage to the respective Big Query tables, using .Net client libraries.

I searched for hours, but didn't get relevant solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's .net sdk does support Big Query and Cloud Storage, but I don't have any first hand examples.  Here's [a link](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs) to the SDK's Supported API page. It should help if you haven't already found it. On this page there is help to using the SDK.

Comment: So, Will i have to use both Big Query API and Google Storage API or either one of them to get my code working?

Comment: You can upload your files through the web interface, but if you want to do things programmaticaly , you will have to use both APIs. Both APIs are accessed similarly from the same SDK.

Answer (score 5):

// IMPORTANT: YOU ALSO NEED TO ACTIVATE Google Cloud Storage JSON API ON YOUR GOOGLE APIS CONSOLE. 
// Google Cloud Storage IS NOT ENOUGH EVEN IF YOU ARE NOT USING JSON ON YOUR .NET CODE

```
         Google.Apis.Storage.v1beta1.Data.Object fileobj = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1beta1.Data.Object();
        fileobj.Media = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1beta1.Data.Object.MediaData();
        fileobj.Media.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        ///READ FILE
        string file = @"C:\2noviembre.csv";

        System.IO.Stream j = new System.IO.FileStream(file,
                              System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                               System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

        //New File Name
        fileobj.Name = "testloco.csv";

        Google.Apis.Storage.v1beta1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload insmedia;
        insmedia = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1beta1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload(storservice, fileobj, "YOURBUCKETNAME", j, "application/octet-stream");
        insmedia.Upload();
        MessageBox.Show("Enviado");
```

Comment: Could you explain what the "storservice" object is and how this is created? I'm struggling to find any other examples for this API and Google's Developer Guide is sending me round in circles...